# How to create a dataset from a select in the database?

Tags: python

I have a database, postgresql and I make the select in the table `iaconsultas`.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="10.1...", port="5432", database="dbname", user="username", password="pwd")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT dsobservacao,cid FROM iaconsultas limit 100")
col_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
# retrieve the records from the database
records = cur.fetchall()

#print(col_names) print columns name
#print(records) print data
```

The variable col_names shows me the names of the colunase records, the values entered in each one.
I am studying for machine learning and would like to create a dataset with the values of the columns and their respective names, for the labels.

DataSet for example:

```
dsoberservacao;cid
valueinserted;idcid
```

Is it possible to do that? How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Might want to take a look at `pandas` and its [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) method. In your case, it would be something like `df = pd.read_sql("SELECT dsobservacao, cid FROM iaconsultas LIMIT 100", conn)`

Comment: Will this create a dataframe with the labels being the names of the columns and their values? Something like df.columns = ['text', 'cid']

Comment: Yes, using your query, the column names will be `dsobservacao` and `cid`. The values will be the values of the columns for the first 100 records that was fetched by the query.